# Are there any normal examples of qt applications using Lottie animations?

Tags: qt, qml, lottie

Are there any normal examples of qt applications using Lottie animations?

Ideally, I would like to use the QML component LottieAnimation (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-lottieqt-lottieanimation.html) for Android and iOS.

It would be cool to see a working example with a Lottie animation, with the correct json file that is in the entire specified size in certain coordinates.

I can't do it right now:

- can't find an animated lottie json file to make the animation work in the app
- can't find a description of the json format for lottie
- can't fit the lottie image into the specified rectangle

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.14
import QtQuick.Window 2.14
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import Qt.labs.lottieqt 1.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    id: idRoot
    width: 360
    height: 653
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    RowLayout {
        id: idControls
        anchors {
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
        }

        Button {
            text: "start"
            onClicked: {
                idLottieAnimation.start()
            }
        }

        ColumnLayout {
            Layout.preferredWidth: 40
            Button {
                text: "+"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                onClicked: {
                    //idContent.scale = idContent.scale * 1.1
                    idLottieAnimation.scale = idLottieAnimation.scale * 1.1
                    idLottieAnimation.x = 0
                    idLottieAnimation.y = 0
                }
            }
            Button {
                text: "-"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                onClicked: {
                    //idContent.scale = idContent.scale / 1.1
                    idLottieAnimation.scale = idLottieAnimation.scale / 1.1
                    idLottieAnimation.x = 0
                    idLottieAnimation.y = 0
                }
            }
        }
        Text {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            wrapMode: Text.Wrap
            text: "window: " + idRoot.width + "-" + idRoot.height + "\n"
                + "lottie: " + idLottieAnimation.width + "-" + idLottieAnimation.height + "\n"
                + idLottieAnimation.x + "-" + idLottieAnimation.y + "\n"
                + "scale: " + idLottieAnimation.scale

        }
    }

    Flickable {
        id: idFlickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.topMargin: idControls.height + 10
        contentWidth: idContent.width;
        contentHeight: idContent.height
        interactive: true
        clip: true


        Rectangle {
            id: idContent
            width: 1000
            height: 1000
            border.width: 1
            border.color: "gray"

            LottieAnimation {
                id: idLottieAnimation
                width: 200  // ignored
                height: 200 // ignored
                loops: LottieAnimation.Infinite //2
                source: "qrc:/lf30_editor_ms0xldnk.json"

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: -1
                    color: "transparent"
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: "red"
                }

                onStatusChanged: {
                    console.log("onStatusChanged:", status, source)
                    if (status === LottieAnimation.Ready) {
                        // any acvities needed before
                        // playing starts go here
                        console.log("gotoAndPlay:", startFrame)
                        gotoAndPlay(startFrame);
                    }
                }
                onFinished: {
                    console.log("Finished playing")
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS support only a fraction of the effects handled by web-player, which makes most of the animation really glitchy. Make sure to check Lordicon.com - they have the biggest number of animated icons supported across Web, iOS, and Android. Useanimations.com have quite fewer icons but most of them work with mobile projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea on the desktop platform. Use a `QQuickWidget` to load a `qml` script within which loading the Lottie json file with `QtLottie`.